# Ionic 2 - Remove white space above ion-navbar

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

How can I remove the white space above the nav-ion?
I'm freaking out with this, I've tried everything without success.
What do you suggest?

Thank you.

[image]

```
  <ion-header>
   <ion-navbar color="danger">
     <ion-title>Suche in der Nähe von mir</ion-title>
       <button ion-button menuToggle>
         <ion-icon name='menu'></ion-icon>
       </button>
   </ion-navbar> 
  </ion-header>
```

Comment: Have you used Chrome inspector to see what's happening with the CSS?

Comment: Yes, Chrome inspector and Firefox Firebug, but with none of them I can come to a conclusion of what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Find it [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/commit/7e4fb159d3a1119424762000f5b22509abd58720) in file ...scss/_tabs.scss

```
+.nav-bar-tabs-top.hide ~ .view-container .tabs-top .tabs{
+  top: 0
+}
+.pane[hide-nav-bar="true"] .has-tabs-top{
+  top:49px
```

This should work!